# Бот, который принимает файл от юзера и сохраняет его в папку на диске

Tags: python, telebot

Телеграм бот получает от пользователя фотографию.
Нужно создать папку с именем user.id, если такое еще нет.
Записать в эту папку файл, который прислал пользователь.
Пишу бота на PYTHON.

```
def save_photo_in_user_folder(message):
directory_for_all_users_photos = "D:\img"
user_id = message.from_user.id
fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
with open("image_def.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Создал метод, который скачивает отправленную картинку в папку проекта. А мне надо ее скачивать в папку: directory_for_all_users_photos = "D:\img_ecomaner"

При чем, там надо проверять. есть ли уже созданная папка с именем user.id или нет, если нет, то создать и записать туда файл.

Также есть вопрос, если юзер отправит несколько файлов, то к имени файла надо будет добавлять что-то. чтобы не перезаписывались, а сохранялись, как в стеке.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_photo_in_user_folder(message):
directory_for_all_users_photos = "D:\img"
user_id = message.from_user.id
fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

if not os.path.isdir(str(user_id)):
   os.mkdir(str(user_id))
os.chdir(str(user_id))
with open("image_def_folder.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

теперь задачка, чтобы имя файл каждый раз было новое, чтобы не перезаписывалось. Пойду читать про строки.